# Is it possible to transfer files in a date range via FTP

Tags: ftp

I need to transfer a large number of files from an FTP server to a new server. There could be thousands of files so I would like to limit it to files that were uploaded in the last three months - is that possible and if so how?

Also is it possible to find out how big the download is likely to be before you start the actually download?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`lftp`](http://lftp.yar.ru/) for that, utilizing its `mirror` command. Here's a snip from the manpage:

```
  mirror [OPTS] [source [target]]

   Mirror specified source directory to local target directory. If target
   directory  ends  with  a  slash,  the source base name is appended to 
   target directory name. Source and/or target can be URLs pointing to 
   directories.


[cut...]
        -N, --newer-than=SPEC    download only files newer than specified time
            --on-change=CMD      execute the command if anything has been changed
            --older-than=SPEC    download only files older than specified time
[...]
```

Definitely have a look at the manual, as there are really many useful options to `mirror` - like `--allow-chown`, `--allow-suid` or `--parallel[=N]` for example. Lftp also works with other access protocols, like `sftp`, `fish` or `http(s)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try mounting it as a filesystem using [`curlftpfs`](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/).
Then copy using `find`.
e.g:

```
mkdir /tmp/mountpoint
curlftpfs ftp://example.com/ /tmp/mountpoint/
cd /tmp/mountpoint
find -mtime +90 -exec cp {} /dest/path/ \;
```

I suspect better solutions exist.